# How to set focus for InputRadio / InputRadioGroup in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I want to set the focus on the `InputRadioGroup` but it appears it doesn't have the `ElementReference` attribute unlike the other Blazor built-in form components. Should I just extend the `InputRadioGroup` and add the `ElementReference` or is there another way to set focus on the `InputRadio` or `InputRadioGroup`?

Comment: Yes, you can add `@ref ` to InputRadioGroup !, I don't get your problem, try to add code.

Comment: Probably because it contains multiple input elements - I would wrap it in a div, grab the ElementReference for that to set focus.

Comment: @user13256346 I did that and if you take a look at the [InputRadioGroup's](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/905557eaca32f5ce9fd17a25e5187ceb7a75cf1c/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputRadioGroup.cs) implementation, it doesn't have the `ElementReference` that I can use to call `FocusAsync`

Comment: @MisterMagoo I've also tried that but it doesn't look like the `InputRadioGroup` is focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, seems like the ability to focus for InputRadio/InputRadioGroup was removed due to some prior issues. They now returned the focus after [I raised the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40804), and it will be included to .NET 7.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the sample below to focus on the InputRadio.

**Vehicle.cs**

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Model
{
    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**file1.js**

```
window.jsfunction = { focusElement: function (id) { const element = document.getElementById(id); element.focus(); } }
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorApp1</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="file1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Index.razor**

```
@inject IJSRuntime js
@page "/"
 
<div>
     <h4> vehicle Selected - @vehicle.Name </h4>
   <EditForm Model="vehicle">
   
   <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="vehicle.Name" >

        @foreach (var option in rdOptions)
        {
            <InputRadio Value="option"  id=@option @onfocus="alrt" /> @option <br />
        }
        
   </InputRadioGroup>

   <br>
    <input Id="idPassWord" Type="password" />

    <button @onclick="clickOK">Set Focus</button>

  </EditForm>
</div>

@code{
    BlazorApp1.Model.Vehicle vehicle=new BlazorApp1.Model.Vehicle(){Name = "auto"};
    List<string> rdOptions = new List<string> { "car", "bus", "auto" };
    private async void clickOK()
    {
        await Focus("car");
    }
     private void alrt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Element focused");
    }
       public async Task Focus(string elementId)
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("jsfunction.focusElement", elementId);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

In the above code example, I am generating the InputRadio on the page which has the OnFocus event. While we try to set the Focus on the InputRadio using the JS code. OnFocus event gets fired and displays the message in a browser console. This proves that InputRadio is getting focused.

Further, you could modify the code as per your own requirements.

Comment: Thanks but I wish there's a non-Javascript based approach that I can take

Comment: How could be not non-Javascript based! `OnFocus` depends on JS solution. I think the answer of @Deepak-MSFT. is correct !

Comment: @user13256346 Yes it is correct, I just prefer not using JavaScript. I'm just thinking if Blazor wants to succeed as the JS alternative then applying focus to a control should come naturally without using interop